# Jest uses loaded module from previous test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Given the code of my tests:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
});

test('render AddCardForm for unknown language', () => {

    act(() => {
        render(<AddCardForm />);
    });

    expect(screen.getByTestId('testNULL')).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('submit form with missing required inputs for AddCardForm', async () => {

    act(() => {
        render(<AddCardForm langSelected="Norwegian" grammarSelected="Noun" wordSetter={() => { }} showModal={() => { }} />);
    });

    act(() => {
        const submitButton = screen.getByTestId("testNorwegianNounSubmit");
        fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId("testAddForm")).toHaveClass("was-validated"));
});
```

Whenever I try to run them it fails with this error:

```
Cannot find module '../langJsons/undefined.json' from 'src/components/AddCardForm.jsx'
```

In my AddCardForm component I dynamically load the JSON file:

```
    useEffect(() => {

        async function getGrammarInputNames(lang, grammar) {
            const file = require(`../langJsons/${lang}.json`);
            const obj = file[`add${grammar}`]['translation'][0][`grammar${grammar}`];
            setGrammarInputNames(Object.values(obj));
        }

        getGrammarInputNames(langSelected, grammarSelected);
    }, [langSelected, grammarSelected]);
```

The thing is, when I comment out the first test then the 2nd one passes without any problem. I assume then, it must keep the "undefined" value under "lang" parameter or something from the previous test. As you can see I've tried using jest.resetModules() and I also did manual cleanup() call. No luck

EDIT: Maybe I should switch from require() to something else? (regular fetch or sth.

EDIT 2: Switching to fetch results in an error "Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80" and I don't know what to do with that :/. All I do is simply fetch(`/langJsons/${lang}.json`). I did try putting JSONs into the 'public' folder and I tried various combinations of '../', './' or '/' at the beginning of the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message. The path for the module has `undefined.json` in it which is what would happen cos it got an undefined for `lang` and you use that for constructing the module name in `getGrammarInputNames(lang, grammar)`

I would suggest to check why lang is getting passed as undefined. May be set a default parameter if no lang is present

```js
getGrammarInputNames(lang = 'eng', grammar)
```